# Get Polynominal Coefficient of non linear equation

Tags: equation-solving, coefficients

I have a non linear equation and want to create a polynomial of that. For this I have to calculate the coefficients. 
The problem is that the equation is a little bit long. So I wanted to do it with *Mathematica*. I tried it with the function `coeffs` but this didn't work.

```
0 =-s2 + s1 + th3*(v1 + (b1 - j2*x)^2/(2*j2) + (j2*x^2)/2 - (b1*(b1 - j2*x))/j2 + j2*x*th1) + ((j2*th3)/2 + (4*j2*v1 - 4*j2*v2 - 2*b1^2 + 2*b2^2 + 4*j2^2*x^2 + j2^2*th3^2 + 4*j2^2*x*th1)^(1/2)/2)^3/(6*j2^2) + x*(v1 + (b1 - j2*x)^2/(2*j2) - (b1*(b1 - j2*x))/j2 + j2*x*th1) - (j2*th3 - 2*b2 + (4*j2*v1 - 4*j2*v2 - 2*b1^2 + 2*b2^2 + 4*j2^2*x^2 + j2^2*th3^2 + 4*j2^2*x*th1)^(1/2))^3/(48*j2^2) - (b1 - j2*x)^3/(6*j2^2) + (j2*x^3)/3 + th1*(v1 + (b1 - j2*x)^2/(2*j2) - (b1*(b1 - j2*x))/j2) + (th3^2*((j2*th3)/2 + (4*j2*v1 - 4*j2*v2 - 2*b1^2 + 2*b2^2 + 4*j2^2*x^2 + j2^2*th3^2 + 4*j2^2*x*th1)^(1/2)/2))/2 + (v1 + (b1 - j2*x)^2/(2*j2) + (j2*x^2)/2 - (b1*(b1 - j2*x))/j2 + j2*x*th1)*(tau - x - th1 - th3 + (j2*th3 - 2*b2 + (4*j2*v1 - 4*j2*v2 - 2*b1^2 + 2*b2^2 + 4*j2^2*x^2 + j2^2*th3^2 + 4*j2^2*x*th1)^(1/2))/(2*j2) + (b1 - j2*x)/j2 + ((j2*th3)/2 + (4*j2*v1 - 4*j2*v2 - 2*b1^2 + 2*b2^2 + 4*j2^2*x^2 + j2^2*th3^2 + 4*j2^2*x*th1)^(1/2)/2)/j2) + (j2*x*th1^2)/2 - (v1*(b1 - j2*x))/j2 - ((j2*th3 - 2*b2 + (4*j2*v1 - 4*j2*v2 - 2*b1^2 + 2*b2^2 + 4*j2^2*x^2 + j2^2*th3^2 + 4*j2^2*x*th1)^(1/2))*(v1 - ((j2*th3)/2 + (4*j2*v1 - 4*j2*v2 - 2*b1^2 + 2*b2^2 + 4*j2^2*x^2 + j2^2*th3^2 + 4*j2^2*x*th1)^(1/2)/2)^2/(2*j2) + th3*((j2*th3)/2 + (4*j2*v1 - 4*j2*v2 - 2*b1^2 + 2*b2^2 + 4*j2^2*x^2 + j2^2*th3^2 + 4*j2^2*x*th1)^(1/2)/2) + (b1 - j2*x)^2/(2*j2) + (j2*x^2)/2 - (b1*(b1 - j2*x))/j2 + j2*x*th1))/(2*j2) - (((j2*th3)/2 + (4*j2*v1 - 4*j2*v2 - 2*b1^2 + 2*b2^2 + 4*j2^2*x^2 + j2^2*th3^2 + 4*j2^2*x*th1)^(1/2)/2)*(v1 + (b1 - j2*x)^2/(2*j2) + (j2*x^2)/2 - (b1*(b1 - j2*x))/j2 + j2*x*th1))/j2 + (b1*(b1 - j2*x)^2)/(2*j2^2) + (((j2*th3)/2 + (4*j2*v1 - 4*j2*v2 - 2*b1^2 + 2*b2^2 + 4*j2^2*x^2 + j2^2*th3^2 + 4*j2^2*x*th1)^(1/2)/2)*(j2*th3 - 2*b2 + (4*j2*v1 - 4*j2*v2 - 2*b1^2 + 2*b2^2 + 4*j2^2*x^2 + j2^2*th3^2 + 4*j2^2*x*th1)^(1/2))^2)/(8*j2^2)
```

or available here

```
expr = ToExpression@Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/91YKVF4N"]
```

There are only parameter in this function excepts of `x` which is the variable.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for: If the expression is an equation you should use `0==...` instead of `0=...` ! Do you want to solve this equation (Solve[...]) or expand around `x=...` (Series[...])?

Comment: There is no function `coeffs`, details are important!. [Edit] your question to *explain in detail* what you need and share the code you say didn't work.

Comment: How would the nonlinear equation and the polynomial that you want to create be related to each other?

Answer (score 1):

If you expression is already a polynomial (your example) then use [`CoefficientList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html).

```
With[
 {
  expr = ToExpression@Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/91YKVF4N"]
  },
 CoefficientList[expr, x]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If not, you can get the [`Series`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html) first.

```
With[
 {
  expr = Exp[x]
  },
 CoefficientList[
  Normal@Series[expr, {x, 0, 5}]
  , x
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Side note:**

Do not confuse [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)(`=`) with [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) (`==`).

Comment: But is this a polynom ? because i have the variable x in the expression of the coefficients